# Using ViewBinding in recyclerview adapter wierldly displays items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewbinding

So I'm using `viewbinding` in my recyclerview adapter here is code snippet.

```
   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FeedItemsViewHolder {
    val viewHolder = FeedItemsViewHolder(ItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener { itemClickListener.onItemClick(it.tag as Item) }
    return viewHolder
}
```

When I use it to inflate the `recylerview` the layout is being displayed wierdly. Here is a screenshot  [image]

However when I inflate the recyclerview normally, the layout is displayed properly. Here is a code snippet and a screenshot

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FeedItemsViewHolder {
    val viewHolder =
        FeedItemsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false))
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener { itemClickListener.onItemClick(it.tag as Item) }
    return viewHolder
}
```

[image]

The problem is caused when I use viewbinding in `onCreateViewHolder`. Nothing else has been changed e.g. layout files etc.
What am I missing ?

Comment: You should also have an `ItemBinding.inflate()` overload that takes the parent `ViewGroup`, too. You want to use that one instead, just like when you're inflating it normally.

Comment: Tried it and it worked. Thanks. So why does android do that ? In one project I didn't use the overloaded version and items were displaying just fine. This time they weren't?

Comment: Because the inflate method you used assumes the layout its inflating is the root (it has no parent), however anything that is not the root layout will eventually need attaching to a parent so its placed and measured correctly as part of the view heirarchy, the fact its "worked" ok before is just by chance based on the layout you previously used.

Comment: I can't comment on the other project without seeing it, but you generally always want to provide the parent `ViewGroup` to the `LayoutInflater`, if possible. If you don't, basically what happens is that all of the `android:layout_*` attributes on the root `<View>` are ignored, and you end up with whatever the specific `ViewGroup` has as its default values, which for `RecyclerView` wraps both width and height.

Comment: @MarkKeen I was inflating the root layout. Doesn't `binding.root` use the `root` by default ? In the past project my layout used a `constraint layout` as the `root view` and this project used a `cardview`  as the `rootview` . The `cardview` 's  children were wrapped inside a `constraint layout`.

Comment: root view of the binding and root of the overall view hierarchy, and parent viewgroup may or not be different things - dependent on context - a child binding can, and should attach itself to the immediate parent view group. View binding is great, but there are some nuances of the view system that need to be understood when usiing the view binding api. @MikeM. gave you a more canonical overview of what is happening.

Comment: Ok. These nuances of the view system, how do I get to understand and know more about them? For instance what you and @MikeM. mentioned in earlier comments, you won't find that in the android docs.  Or it's a matter of experience?

Comment: Its well documented in `LayoutInflater` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of working ViewBinding for RecyclerView Adapter

```
class SampleViewHolder (rootItemView: StorefrontCategoryItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(**rootItemView.root**) {
    val rootView = rootItemView.rootViewItem

}
```

And in adapter

```
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SampleViewHolder {

        return SampleViewHolder (StorefrontCategoryItemBinding.inflate(context.layoutInflater))
    }
```